# How can I find the build-dest-position of a cc file

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

For example `common_shape_fns_test.cc`, I search this string and find it in the `BUILD` file , then I search `tf_cc_tests` . At last I can't find any hint.

I want to run it directly and debug it , so I need to find the position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for the location of the binary Bazel built, it will be printed in Bazel's output, e.g.,

```
$ bazel build //foo/bar:baz
...
Target //foo/bar:baz up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/foo/bar/baz
```

`bazel-bin/foo/bar/baz` is the build output.

In general, though, you can always find the output file when you know the BUILD file that generated it.  If the BUILD file is `tensorflow/core/BUILD`, then the output will be under `bazel-bin/tensorflow/core` (or, if it's a genrule, `bazel-genfiles/tensorflow/core`).

Comment: Yes , build it first . `bazel build //tensorflow/core:framework_common_shape_fns_test` .     Then I can run it :
`bazel-bin/tensorflow/core/framework_common_shape_fns_test`

Comment: Sorry, are you looking for something else?

Comment: Yes , in the future

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bazel query`. IE, using the [recipe](https://bazel.io/versions/master/docs/query-how-to.html#What_build_rule_contains_file_ja) from Bazel Query howto

```
fullname=$(bazel query tensorflow/core/framework/common_shape_fns_test.cc)
bazel query "attr('srcs', $fullname, ${fullname//:*/}:*)"
>>

//tensorflow/core:framework_common_shape_fns_test
//tensorflow/core:all_files
```